# Careers company listing hides long benefit descriptor

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

I've populated the benefits section with some long descriptions that span 3 lines of text.

The third line of text is hidden with no indication that there's more text.

Company link: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/company/nextdoor

Wordy benefit description: "Dinners delivered Monday - Thursday, and constantly stocked kitchen."

Comment: What is the url of your company page so we can take a look at it?

Comment: That must be one hell of a benefit.

Comment: I've updated the OP with extra data. Didn't want the link posting to seem like a lame self-advertising method.

Comment: Seems like the second left item is truncated "100% Company Paid medical, dental, and vision plans for you and your family", "family" spanning the third line, hidden from view by the next item below.

Comment: @SamuelLiew, that too. I just brought one example since I think it's the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved sometime previously, just cleaning this up.